# Returning multiple values in UDF

Tags: user-defined-functions, vertica

I have written an AggregateFactory Vertica UDF which returns a single value

```
getReturnTypes(si,columnTypes args,columnTypes returnTypes){

 returnTypes.addVarbinary(512);
 //I want to add second returnType
returnTypes.addFloat("");
} 

getProtoType(si,columnTypes args,columnTypes returnTypes){
returnTypes.addVarbinary(512);
 //I want to add second returnType
returnTypes.addFloat("");
}
```

this is not working, how can I return two values from an AggregateFactory UDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. User Defined Aggregate Functions (as explained in the [fine manual](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingVertica/UDx/AggregateFunctions/AggregateFunctions.htm%3FTocPath%3DExtending%2520Vertica%7CDeveloping%2520User-Defined%2520Extensions%2520(UDxs)%7CAggregate%2520Functions%2520(UDAFs)%7C_____0)) return ONE value per group. You might want to write a User Defined **Transform** Function (maybe a multi-phase Transform Function).